# What is the best way to make a post page with comments. Laravel - vue.js - inertia-vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I'm trying to make a discussion forum with comments, this is what it looks like 
[image]

This page has the route

`Route::get('forums/comment/{id}', 'ForumController@comment');`

In the controller

```
public function comment($id){
    $forum = DiscussionForum::where('id', $id)
        ->with('comment', 'user')->first();
    $comment = Reply::with('discussionForum', 'user')
        ->where('discussion_forum_id', $forum->id)
        ->orderByDesc('updated_at')->get();

    return Inertia::render('Forum/Comment.vue', [
        'forum' => $forum,
        'comments' => $comment
    ]);
}
```

My question is how to then save this comment in the comment controller, in my vue file I have this method that gets executed when I press the save button

```
submit() {
    this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
        if (valid) {
            if (!this.form.id) {
                this.$inertia.post('comments', {
                    comment: this.form.comment,
                    forum_id :this.form.id,
                }).then(() => this.refresh())
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    this.reset();
    });
},
```

I also have this route for the comments

```
Route::resource('comments', 'ReplyController');
```

For the store function I have this

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    $comment = new Reply();
    $comment->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $comment->discussion_forum_id = $request->forum_id;
    $comment->comment = $request->comment;
    $comment->comment_time = Carbon::now();
    $comment->save();
    DB::commit();
}
```

The problem is I get this error when I try to save the comment

> The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

How can I fix this? or What is a better way to do this?

Comment: For some reason I'm suspecting that you are making a reques to another route. Can you confirm that you are indeed making a request to /comments?

Comment: What is the action attribute on your form?

Comment: @Charlie I'm trying to save the comment from this url `/forums/comment/{id}` and trying to send it here `comments` to save it with the store function in the ReplyController (CommentController)

Comment: you should follow @iCrashOne answer because its quite hard to debug without having further information

Answer (score 1):

To be able to find the issue, you need to debug. I would do the following:

- In the developer console, check the network tab to inspect the request to see the url and data being send.
- In the console run `php artisan route:list` to see if all your routes are listed. Also try clearing the cache with `php artisan route:cache`
- Other option could be changing the resource route `Route::resource('comments', 'ReplyController');` for individual routes for each method just to find the problem.